# meaning of \cite{../foo/bar:baz} in sphinx-generated LaTeX

Tags: pdftex, citing, sphinx

Trying to debug (after update to sphinx 1.8.5 from 1.7) documentation biulding produced by sphinx, we see in generated LaTeX files calls to `\cite`
with an argument involving a path to a file, like
`\cite{../foo/bar:baz}`, where `baz` is the actual citation label.

What should this mean? I have never seen such references in my 25+ years working with LaTeX.
Indeed, we have `thebibliography` in the file `../foo/bar.tex`, but is it supposed to work? Or this is a bug in the sphinx LaTeX support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To latex `.`, `:` and `/` are just normal catcode 12 non letter characters so

```
\cite{../foo/bar:baz}
```

is a perfectly good call to `\cite` with no more significance than

```
\cite{zzzzzz}
```

presumably the tex generator is using the filename as some kind of device to generate unique citation keys, but latex doesn't need to know that.

Comment: Just to add that there are some other characters that should not appear in `\cite`. A comma is used to separate several keys, so that is out. One part of cite is basically a `\label`-`\ref` mechanism, which rules out `~`, ```\```, `#` and a few other special symbols. If one uses BibTeX (or `biblatex` with Biber) the set of valid characters is further reduced by restrictions from the backend. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/408530/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96454/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/243729/35864